# M2E Maven Plugin: Importing Maven project is throwing error in Eclipse JUNO

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-juno, m2e

I have an existing project in maven which is working fine in other remote env which i
dont have any access, I dont know what is the issue in my env, the same project is working
in other remote env.

My Env Details are:-

Java1.7
Tomcat7.x
Eclipse Juno,Build id: 20120614-1722
Plugin Details: M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse

The below error is coming while importing the project and after selecting pom.xml.

No marketplace entries found to handle maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile in Eclipse

[image]

Comment: I also tried out of eclipse using command prompt and i can see below error after executing : mvn archetype:generate

Comment: C:\Users\Amit\myapp>mvn archetype:generate
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
 Downloading: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/maven/plug
 ins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
 [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
 n-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or on
 e of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
 for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window > Preferences > Maven Installations and then deactivate the Embedded and add your own installation.

Answer (score 0):

I would check:

- That Eclipse Maven build settings are using a JDK and not a JRE
- Check the actual compiler settings in the POM. Maybe the source and target should be explicitly set to 1.7.

It's also worth checking if this runs properly with mvn from the command line to rule out whether it is truly a Maven or IDE issue.